# Select random value from the response json with a validation

Tags: jmeter

When I send a request to an api end point, the following json is coming in my response.

```
{
    "entities": {
        "practitioners": {
            "f1d26a4b-c489-493d-bccf-7b9c8b92ecac": {
                "fullAvatarUrl": null,
                "id": "f1d26a4b-c489-493d-bccf-7b9c8b92ecac",
                "accountId": "ef757dba-f0d5-4464-a338-4a810e02bf47",
                "pmsId": "1",
                "type": "Dentist",
                "isActive": true,
                "isHidden": false
            },
            "ee87642d-c9a6-4a9d-b99a-a96501f27a7b": {
                "fullAvatarUrl": null,
                "id": "ee87642d-c9a6-4a9d-b99a-a96501f27a7b",
                "accountId": "ef757dba-f0d5-4464-a338-4a810e02bf47",
                "pmsId": "2",
                "type": "Hygienist",
                "isActive": true,
                "isHidden": false
            },
            "d0aeb9eb-f267-45ad-8cdf-eada1155c274": {
                "fullAvatarUrl": null,
                "id": "d0aeb9eb-f267-45ad-8cdf-eada1155c274",
                "accountId": "ef757dba-f0d5-4464-a338-4a810e02bf47",
                "pmsId": "3",
                "type": "Dentist",
                "isActive": true,
                "isHidden": false
            },
            "2f641e8e-c5d6-4fdf-8fbe-f99fe837f441": {
                "fullAvatarUrl": null,
                "id": "2f641e8e-c5d6-4fdf-8fbe-f99fe837f441",
                "accountId": "ef757dba-f0d5-4464-a338-4a810e02bf47",
                "pmsId": "4",
                "type": "Hygienist",
                "isActive": true,
                "isHidden": false
            }
        }
    },
    "result": [
        "f1d26a4b-c489-493d-bccf-7b9c8b92ecac",
        "ee87642d-c9a6-4a9d-b99a-a96501f27a7b",
        "d0aeb9eb-f267-45ad-8cdf-eada1155c274",
        "2f641e8e-c5d6-4fdf-8fbe-f99fe837f441"
    ]
}
```

**problem statement:** I want to select any one from the above 4 random value(want to select the practitioners id and which are sitting at the first element under  practitioners) with a validation that `isActive` should be `true` and `isHidden` should be `false`.

I have tried using the JSON extractor using the expression `$.entities.practitioners` and match number `0`

But it is not selecting the any one rather it select all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this approach can help you,

add a `JSR223 PostProcessor` to your http request and after that please add the following groovy script to the `PostProcessor`

`Note: this is only to select the random PractitionersId` for the validation just use the similar logic.

```
import groovy.json.*

def response = prev.responseDataAsString ;
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response) ;
def sizeResultPractitioners = json.result.size();
Random rnd = new Random()
def randomResultPractitioners = rnd.nextInt(sizeResultPractitioners);
log.info("---------->"+randomResultPractitioners);
log.info("---------->"+json.result[randomResultPractitioners]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jyoti, this really help

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns this JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   def ids = []
   json.entities.practitioners.each { practitioner ->
       if (practitioner.value.isActive && !practitioner.value.isHidden) {
           ids.add(practitioner.key)
       }
   }

   def randomId = ids.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ids.size()))
   vars.put('randomId', randomId)
   ```
3. That's it, you should be able to access the random ID as `${randomId}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)